# Round Icon Badge using CALayer and CATextLayer On UIBUtton

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

[![enter image description here][1]][1]Can any one share their code relating to show round Badge number icon on UIButton on Top right Corner Using CALayer And CATextLayer and Add to UIButton

Thanks In advance

Comment: https://github.com/mustafaibrahim989/MIBadgeButton-Swift check this lib

Comment: Thanks I have already checked this but I want to use specifically CALAyer and CATextLayer on Already created UIButton in My sliding Menu

Answer (score -1):

For your badge, you can use only label for showing the badge on button specially.

```
let label = UILabel()
label.clipsToBounds = true
label.layer.cornerRadius = label.font.pointSize * 1.2 / 2
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
label.text = " Some Text "; // note spaces before and after text
```

And For reusability, you can create the category or extension for this code.

Comment: Thanks, The Code u have shared will Create ROUND Label With text.

What I want is I have whats app Like app on that I have to show Badge Number on Sliding Menu In Case we receive notification same how we show badge number on TabBar Item .
Badge feature is inbuilt with TabBar but not with Button.
So Instead of Two IBOultet I would like to add Round Layer With text on UIBUtton Top right Corner .

Comment: Yes this will create round label with text so that u can stick it to the sliding menu button to the upper right corner using Autolayout. Do you understand?

Comment: But how I will add this label on UIButton as addSubview ?
Because need to bound to that button Top right Corner frame.

Comment: Yes, you can add this label as subview not to the button which is not possible but to the superview either using code or constraints.

Comment: I have added the image to know what exactly I want For this I am using Third Party API : https://github.com/uias/Tabman

Comment: Thats why I want to draw CALLAyer with CATExtlayer that will add to UIBUtton top right corner. So no need to add constraints and all